# Reducing TypeScript Type possibility with recursive typing

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Since TypeScript allows Advanced Type definition, I want to experiment a lot this approach, but it's not as easy as I expected.

For example, I want to have a kind of "wizard-step-by-step" method:

```
function fillWizardOptions<T>() {
     return <P extends T> (value:  P) => {
         return fillWizardOptions<Exclude<T, P>>();
     }
}
```

So each time I call a chained sub-function, I want to lose the previous option, but currently, `Exclude` doesn't work as I was expected:

```
fillWizardOptions<string|number|boolean>()
     ('foo')
     ('bar');// Expect here of have only number|boolean, but I still have string|number|boolean
```

Probably I miss something.

Also, if someone know where I can find a kind of `playground` like for [RegEx101](https://regex101.com/)

Thanks.

Update: forget to mention that I'm using TypeScript 3.3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, for the first call, the `<P>` instead of implementing `string` type, it has the `'foo'` type. So that's why it didn't exclude `string` from `T`. Therefore, it should work if you write `('foo' as string)` or `(<string>'foo')`

Comment: Wow! It's exactly like that!... Not easy to deal with literal value and primitive...
By using an `enum`, it's definitely more elegant and no need to deal with casting anymore.
Thanks!